# Keep getting failed connections to db

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a project and whenever I try to connect to the db from my development machine , I always get this error

```
Cannot connect to the database because: Host '**' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

where ** is the ip address blocked.

So I flush my hosts yesterday and it happened again today. But the credentials for the db is correct. What can be other reasons causing this? How do I go about investigating this?

Comment: please specify connection code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use this for increase maximum error encounter with mysql:

```
shell> mysqld_safe --max_connect_errors=10000 &
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that mysqld has received many connection requests from the given host that were interrupted in the middle.

By default, mysqld blocks a host after 10 connection errors. You can adjust the value by setting max_connect_errors at server startup:

```
shell> mysqld_safe --max_connect_errors=10000 &
```

The value can also be set at runtime:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;
```

For more details refer, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html